# 2.8/Grease P/How to rotate only a few strokes by the Cursor?

Tags: grease-pencil

I see there's a tool called Cursor, but nothing happens when I click on the canvas with it. I was hoping it would allow me to choose a different location for the cursor so I could rotate by it. As if defining a Pivot point.
DPC

Answer (score 0):

My 3D Cursor was not showing, this is what was confusing me.
Thanks to dan2 from blenderartists to demystify this.

[image]